# Creating a transient relational property

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I think this is a simple issue but I have somehow leaked object in core data. I have a simple one to one relation in core data.

```
       Person           <-------->         Address

        -name                                -city
        -email                               -country
```

The person model was relatively simple with just few attributes. But, I wanted to add the getter in Person class to access the city and country from the person class itself. So, I did something like,

```
@interface Person:NSManagedObject
    @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) Address *address;
    -(NSString*)city;
    -(NSString*)country;
@end


@implementation Person
  -(NSString*)city{
     [self willAccessValueForKey:@"address"];
     NSString *c = [self valueForKeyPath:@"address.city"];
     [self didAccessValueForKey:@"address"];
   }

   -(NSString*)country{
     [self willAccessValueForKey:@"address"];
     NSString *c = [self valueForKeyPath:@"address.country"];
     [self didAccessValueForKey:@"address"];
   }

@end
```

With these getter I have been able to access the city with just simple getters in Person model as;

```
    person.city   and  person.country
```

But, I feel this is not the correct way to do it. How do I implement this feature to ensure that the memory is not leaked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access city or country directly from Person, 
you can access like....

```
Person.Address.city
Person.Address.country
```

and no need of implement the:

```
-(NSString*)city;
-(NSString*)country;
```

Comment: No I have some situation where I need to access the value. The way I am doing correctly fetches the value but there is some leak with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return statements in the code, but I guess they are there in the actual code you are using.

I do not see any leak in the code itself. Remember however that you are responsible for faulting everything when done as Core Data relationships inherently create retain cycles. See [Core Data And Retain Cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789974/core-data-and-retain-cycles)

Answer (score 1):

As Ganee says, you can just access

```
person.address.city
```

but if you absolutely need the city method, you should use the generated properties:

```
- (NSString*)city {
    return address.city;
}
```

though this hides your relationship access so make sure that's what you want.

In regards to your memory leak, you need a really, really, really good reason to not use ARC for new projects.