# How to deal with Core Data retain cycles

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, memory, automatic-ref-counting

The core data guidelines recommend that you model your relationships with an inverse. No problems there.

Interestingly though if you Load an object A that has a to many relationship to B and walk the object graph you end up with a retain cycle and the memory is never freed.

For a simple object graph you can just call  refreshObject:mergeChanges: on A to re-fault the object so that relationships are no longer strong references.

If you have a complicated object graph though this is a pain because you need to call it on every object you have touched. It seems like a pretty important consideration when using core data yet there is only one paragraph on this topic in Apples documentation.

I am just wondering how other people handle this? A long running app would slowly just consume more and more memory without some sort of manual process to force objects to revert to faults.

Are there any known patterns for dealing with this. I'd imagine so since lots of people use Core Data I just can't find any recommendations

Comment: How do you know you get into retain cycles in the first place? Is using ARC an option?

Comment: ARC does not prevent retain cycles, it isn't the same as garbage collection (I am already using ARC). The example above states how a retain cycle can happen in core data under normal usage.

Comment: A lot of people use core data, you're right. It's been around for years. You need to check your assertion in your second paragraph. Is it the case? If it was a flaw in core data, people would be talking about it, don't you think?

Comment: This is the behaviour as stated in apples docs. There is another stack overflow question on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789974/core-data-and-retain-cycles. Apple docs also say this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html. Maybe I am misunderstanding this but I don't see how?

Comment: Im not saying its a flaw because they specify a way to break retain cycles, I am more wondering if there is a better way to do this when you have a large object graph or any particular core data usage patterns to avoid / reduce this.

Comment: According to the SO post to which you link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789974/core-data-and-retain-cycles), you should break the retain cycles with refreshObject:mergeChanges:. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: I'm looking at the same thing. It seems like a very poor way to break retain cycles. It requires explicit intervention that wouldn't otherwise be needed. I believe you also need to ensure that the object has no unsaved data before you call this.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring several aspects of core data when making your assertions. If you fetch an object, let's say object A, which has a one-to-many relationship to object B, when you fetch A, you will have all the objects on B which are related to A. A one to many relationship creates the list of objects related to A and contains them on an NSSet property of your NSManagedObject subclass. Note that these objects are in a faulted state, and the memory footprint from this is insignificant. If you manipulate the objects in the relationship, core data will unfault these objects when necessary. You do not have to do anything to get this behavior. If you want to trigger the faulting behavior yourself to send the objects to fault again, you can use refreshObject:mergeChanges:. If you do not send them back to fault, the faulting behavior will be trigger again eventually.

Comment: "If you do not send them back to fault, the faulting behavior will be trigger again eventually." Is that in the docs because I didn't see it? I was under the impression you have to do it manually but if thats the case then I have nothing to worry about.